# Multiple Models Single View Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two Models which i need to combine into one view. The First Model

```
class MainTransaction
    public MainTransaction()
    {
        this.SubTransactions = new HashSet<SubTransaction>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string bank { get; set; }
    public string narration { get; set; }
    public string RecievedFrom { get; set; }
    public string VoucherType { get; set; }
    public string VoucherNo { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string DistrictCode { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<SubTransaction> SubTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

The Second Model

```
public class SubTransaction
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int MainTransactionId { get; set; }
    public int HeadCode { get; set; }
    public int subsidiary { get; set; }
    public int fund { get; set; }
    public int district { get; set; }
    public int sector { get; set; }
    public int gender { get; set; }
    public double debit { get; set; }
    public double credit { get; set; }
    public string payee { get; set; }
    public string ChequeNo { get; set; }
    public string AccountDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual District District1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Fund Fund1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Head4 Head4 { get; set; }
    public virtual MainTransaction MainTransaction { get; set; }
    public virtual Sector Sector1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Subsidiary Subsidiary1 { get; set; }
}
```

Both Models are related. On the basis of this model i have to construct a View Voucher which will contain properties from both the Models. To pass this model to a view, i have created another model Voucher

```
 public class Voucher
{
   public  MainTransaction mt {get;set;
   public List<SubTransaction> st {get;set;};
}
```

The View
     @model ModelFormBindingTutorial.Models.Voucher
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "CreateVoucher";
     }

```
<form method="post" action="StoreVoucher">
  <table border="1" class="table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" >
    <tr>
        <th>TransactionDate</th>
        <th>Bank</th>
        <th>Narration</th>
        <th>RecievedFrom</th>
        <th>VoucherType</th>
        <th>Voucher No.</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>DistrictCode</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mt.TransactionDate, new { @Value = "12/12/2014" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mt.bank, new { @Value = "Allied Bank" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mt.narration,new { @Value = "Some Stuff Going on"})</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mt.RecievedFrom, new { @Value = "Recieved From" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mt.VoucherType, new { @Value = "BPV" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mt.VoucherNo, new { @Value = "BPV-12-2016-GGG" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mt.description, new { @Value = "Some Description" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mt.DistrictCode, new { @Value = "001" })</td>


    </tr>

</table><br />

<table border="1" class="table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>

    </th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:120px">HeadCode</th>
        <th style="width:70px">Subsidiary</th>
        <th style="width:70px">Funds</th>
        <th style="width:70px">District</th>
        <th style="width:70px">Sector</th>
        <th style="width:70px">Gender</th>
        <th style="width:200px">Debit</th>
        <th style="width:200px">Credit</th>
        <th>Payee</th>
        <th>ChequeNo</th>
        <th>AccountDescription</th>

    </tr>

    @for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
       <tr>


          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].HeadCode, new { @Value = "001" })</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].subsidiary, new { @Value = "002" })</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].fund, new { @Value = "003" })</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].district, new { @Value = "004" })</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].sector, new { @Value = "005" })</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].gender, new { @Value = "01" })
           </td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].debit, new { @Value = "40000" })</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].credit,new { @Value = "5005"})</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].payee, new { @Value = "Biltoon Gulab" })</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].ChequeNo, new { @Value = "4204" })</td>
           <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].AccountDescription, new { @Value = "Some Description" })</td>


     </tr>

    }
</table><br />

<div style="float:right; width:400px" >
    <input size="23" type="text" value="Total" />
</div>


<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
```

And then in the View i pass the Voucher Model. When the form is submitted, in the Controller Action, An object of MainTransaction is created, but SubTransaction always Returns Null. I can't figure out why MainTransaction object is created, while SubTransaction is Null.

Any suggestions

Comment: Yes: If you don't set SubTransaction before submitting the form, it is always null. Try "Html.HiddenFor(x => x.st)" (in the view) or something like that to preserve Voucher.st.

Comment: First problem is that they are fields, not properties (fields are not bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`). They are also not public - `public MainTransaction mt { get; set } public List<SubTransaction> st { get; set; }`

Comment: Are you setting any data to SubTransaction in View? if not then why are you passing it from controller to view?

Comment: But why do you need the this anyway since `MainTransaction` already contains `ICollection<SubTransaction>`? You do need a view model, but it needs to contain properties of `MainTransaction` that you want in the view, not a property which is `MainTransaction`

Comment: This View is used to store data in two tables. @StephenMuecke i edited the code in the question.

Comment: And is its not binding, its because your view is wrong or the POST method is wrong - you have not shown eiher.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added View to the question

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mt.TransactionDate)` etc - NEVER attempt to set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. And `for (var i = 0; i < Model.st.Count.; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].HeadCode) .... }` and populate the model with 3 `SubTransaction` objects before you pass the model to the view (Indexers must start at zero). And I assume the POST method parameter is `public ActionResult StoreVoucher(Voucher model)`?

Comment: Yes it is public ActionResult StoreVoucher(Voucher v)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and had solved the way.

1. Send your model value from controller.
2. Change your voucher Model.
3. Get the List item count in cshtml.
4. Loop through your ListLength count.

It's working. Check at your end.

Code:

Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Voucher v = new Voucher();
        SubTransaction objst = new SubTransaction();
        objst.HeadCode = 001;
        objst.subsidiary = 2;
        objst.fund = 3;
        objst.district = 4;
        objst.sector = 5;
        objst.gender = 61;
        objst.payee = "payee1";
        v.st.Add(objst);

        objst = new SubTransaction();
        objst.HeadCode = 001;
        objst.subsidiary = 2;
        objst.fund = 3;
        objst.district = 4;
        objst.sector = 5;
        objst.gender = 61;
        objst.payee = "payee2";
        v.st.Add(objst);

        return View(v);
    }
```

Voucher Model:

```
 public class Voucher
    {
        public Voucher()
        {
            st = new List<SubTransaction>();
        }
        public MainTransaction mt { get; set; }
        public List<SubTransaction> st { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@{
    int ListLength=0;
    if(Model.st!=null)
    {
     ListLength = Model.st.Count();
    }
}




     @for (var i = 0; i < ListLength; i++)
        {
             <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].HeadCode)</td> // If you want to load data from model
             @*<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.st[i].HeadCode,new { @Value = "001" })</td>*@ // if you want to hard code the data.
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Output in this Image. The length of the List is 0 and gives Null Reference Exception http://i66.tinypic.com/mh6kyb.png

Comment: where are you getting null reference exception(view or controller). Are you change your Voucher model ? did you returning voucher model from Action method. The same code is working fine at my end.

Comment: Controller i attached the picture in my previous comment

Comment: Please note my Index() method. I am returning Voucher Model as 'return view(v)'. Send the model like that.

Comment: Can you please mention your Action method that returns that view initially.

Comment: public ActionResult CreateVoucher()
        {
            return View(new Voucher());
        }

Comment: Not new voucher (). Please return model with data.populate data in your model first what I exactly did in my index method.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: can you please share your controller and view ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Partial View** to access multiple models properties inside single view.

Comment: OP is asking why their code is not working (not asking for bad alternatives)